# REgular Expression using Java

Tags: java, regex

I am Using Regular Expression to break the string, I am trying to break the string but In reqular Expressions I am missing some format. Can any one please let me know where i went wrong.

```
String betweenstring="['Sheet 1$'].[DEPTNO] AS [DEPTNO]";
System.out.println("betweenstring: "+betweenstring);
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+[.]\\w+");
Matcher matchers=pattern.matcher(betweenstring);    
while(matchers.find())
{       
    String filtereddata=matchers.group(0);          
    System.out.println("filtereddata: "+filtereddata);
}
```

I need to break like this:

```
['Sheet 1$']
[DEPTNO] AS [DEPTNO]
```

Comment: Define what "break the string" means

Comment: I have Updated Please once check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your very specific input, this regex works.

```
([\w\[\]' $]+)\.([\w\[\]' $]+)
```

Capture group one is before the period, capture group 2, after. To escape this for a Java string:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([\\w\\[\\]' $]+(\\.*[\\w\\[\\]' $]+)");
```

However, it would be much easier to split the string on the literal dot, if this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
String[] pieces = between.split("\\.");
System.out.println(pieces[0]);    
System.out.println(pieces[1]);
```

Output:

```
['Sheet 1$']
[DEPTNO] AS [DEPTNO]
```